# Shipping Table Rates not working in Magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2

I am trying for two weeks to enable Shipping Table Rates but it seem doesn't work, So I decided to create a new fresh Magento 2.4.3 and import a new csv file, and again it's not shown in the checkout, Is this a bug in this version?

Comment: GitHub is a better place for the bug report

Comment: Table rate shipping is working fine in 2.4.3. You may need to debug issue. please check var/log files and flush cache as well.

Comment: Did you remember to properly set the store view?